# php abbreviating numbers with K/M

Tags: php, function, numbers, abbreviation

The function below finds the number, rounds it off and puts a K or M on the end of it

IE: 25000 becomes 25K

```
function abbr_no($number) {
 $number  = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
 $numbers = array('', 'K', 'M');
if ($number == 0) { 
 return('n/a'); 
 } else {
 return (round($number/pow(10000, ($i = floor(log($number, 10000)))), 0) . $numbers[$i]);
 }
}
```

and so it basically does what I want, but as is for a number like *389345* it rounds it off and spits out *39K* (as it should) however I would like the result to be *398K* (3 digit number)

Now in the last return line:

```
0) . $numbers[$i]);
```

if I change the 0 to a 1 the result becomes *39.8K* but again I don't want the decimal point so I am currently stuck and have hit a brickwall

As always all help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: It _should not_ spit out _39K_, but the _correct 389K_ (unless you are doing something I don't understand). Change `10000`'s to `1000`'s.

Comment: shouldn't 389345 not become 39k? I think there's something wrong, but can't verify for now..

Comment: Ok time for bed I think lol ..thanks Wrikken to many 0's was the issue :)

Comment: _389345 it rounds it off and spits out 39K (as it should) however I would like the result to be 398K_ | **Correcting:** 389345 it rounds it off and spits out 390K (as it should) however I would like the result to be 389K. Did anybody tried to edit this part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to convert on all sorts of scales,

```
function humanize($val, $postfix)
{
    foreach ($postfix as $p=>$div) {
        $t=round($val/$div) . $p;
        if (strlen($t)<(3+strlen($p))) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return trim($t);
}
```

e.g.

```
$postfix=array(''=>1, 'K'=>1000,'M'=>1000000,'B'=>1000000000);
```

To answer the original question,

```
$postfix=array('walnut' => 0.16, 'chicken egg'=>0.35, 
    'grapefruit' => 1, 'bulgarian airbag' => 1.1,
    'bulgarian funbag'=>3.27, 'football' => 11.07, 
    'olympic swim pool' => 4780114, 'known universe'=>1.17456E4933);
```

for the [Vulture Central Weights and Measures Soviet](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2007/08/24/vulture_central_standards/) volume standard.

Comment: @Bazuka Much better. Why not edit the answer to include this correction?

Answer (score 0):

without editing much of your code you can add additional if statement
test if the modular division by 1 
yournumber%1

```
($i = floor(log($number, 10000)))), 0) % 1
```

gives you 0
if it doesnt then

multiply your number by 10 (you can make it a while statement so it multiplies it by 10 until there are no spaces after decimal point)

then return that number

so if you use your_number like 39.8 as an example it would look like this

```
while(your_number%1 != 0){
 your_number*=10;
}
return your_number;
```

This a quick fix but its definitely not the best way to code this